# Angular2 pipes time interval on json data

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-pipe

I'm building an angular2 app with highcharts. I have set up my data importing service and i can already proces the data to go into highcharts, but now i want to group the data on 5 minute intervals. The data i have is in epochtime. 
now i want to group all the data with 5 minute intervals. I saw that using angular pipes is probably the best way to go.

Dataservice > pipe > component > highcharts

The question is: *what kind of pipe do i have to use to group the epochtime data with intervals of 5 min starting each day from 0:00. (so 0:00 to 0:05, 0:05 to 0:10)*

Comment: have you tried to implement something?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer do you want, but you need a custom pipe. You receive a value (an array of data I guess), and then you transform that array into another grouping the data with your custom rules

Comment: I am wondering, if Highstock dataGrouping won't help you with your issue: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping